# Redraw Datatable with json data with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I want to redraw my datatable if I press the plus button. However I get the error message that the JSON is not well formed even though it is a valid JSON. I can even see the two objects from the JSON data with debugging. Can somebody help?

```
<table class="table display sticky-header" id="tabelle_benutzerHead" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead >
        <tr>
            <th>Uhrzeit</th>
            <th>SpNr</th>
            <th>Platz</th>
            <th>Heimmannschaft</th>
            <th>Gastmannschaft</th>
            <th>Freispiele</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr id="Row1">
                <td>08:00</td>
                <td>134</td>
                <td>Platz 1</td>
                <td>Team 5</td>
                <td>Team 3</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-default AddDaten" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Row2">
                <td>09:00</td>
                <td>76</td>
                <td>Platz 3</td>
                <td>Team 7</td>
                <td>Team 1</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-default AddDaten" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Row3">
                <td>17:30</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>Platz 11</td>
                <td>Team 2</td>
                <td>Team 9</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-default AddDaten" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



var oTable = $('#tabelle_benutzerHead').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "info": false,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    rowReorder: true
});

$('#tabelle_benutzerHead').delegate('button.AddDaten', 'click', function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the parent row of the clicked button                    
        var rowId = $(row).attr('id'); // clicked RowId

        var response = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api.json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { 
                'rowId': rowId
            }).done(function (result) {

            oTable.clear().draw();
            oTable.rows.add(result);
            oTable.draw();
         });    
    });
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
   "data": [
       ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
       ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"]
   ]
}
```

Comment: Is api.json a file ? if yes why is it a post request ?

Comment: The issue happens when there is a mismatch between the number of columns and the data you provide it..

Comment: Yes it is a file but I originally wanted to post the id to an url and get the json as a response but had the problem with the same origin policy.

Comment: But I have six columns.

Comment: And it does not change even it is a get request.

Comment: Which datatable component are you using ?

Comment: Also why are you calling two times?

Comment: I am using datatable from https://datatables.net/ and yes I called it falsely two times but even if I remove it the problem remains.